# Python and lmfit: Fit Multiple Data Sets with different lengths

Tags: python, lmfit

On the example of fit with multiple data sets from lmfit documentation, the data variable have rows of equal length.

I tried to adapt the example to run the fit using datasets with different lengths. The only change I made was changing the length of the x variable for each of the five different data sets, but it didn't worked out.

The error I got was:

> data = np.array(data)
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (5,) + inhomogeneous part.

And here is the code I tried to run:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_fit

def gauss(x, amp, cen, sigma):
    "basic gaussian"
    return amp*np.exp(-(x-cen)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

def gauss_dataset(params, i, x):
    """calc gaussian from params for data set i
    using simple, hardwired naming convention"""
    amp = params['amp_%i' % (i+1)].value
    cen = params['cen_%i' % (i+1)].value
    sig = params['sig_%i' % (i+1)].value
    return gauss(x, amp, cen, sig)

def objective(params, x, data):
    """ calculate total residual for fits to several data sets held
    in a 2-D array, and modeled by Gaussian functions"""
    ndata, nx = data.shape
    resid = 0.0*data[:]
    # make residual per data set
    for i in range(ndata):
        resid[i, :] = data[i, :] - gauss_dataset(params, i, x)
    # now flatten this to a 1D array, as minimize() needs
    return resid.flatten()

# create 5 datasets

data = []
for i in np.arange(5):
    #Now x has different length each iteration
    x  = np.linspace( -1, 2, 151+i)
    params = Parameters()
    amp   =  0.60 + 9.50*np.random.rand()
    cen   = -0.20 + 1.20*np.random.rand()
    sig   =  0.25 + 0.03*np.random.rand()
    dat   = gauss(x, amp, cen, sig) + np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.1)
    data.append(dat)

# data has shape (5, 151)
data = np.array(data)
assert(data.shape) == (5, 151)

# create 5 sets of parameters, one per data set
fit_params = Parameters()
for iy, y in enumerate(data):
    fit_params.add( 'amp_%i' % (iy+1), value=0.5, min=0.0,  max=200)
    fit_params.add( 'cen_%i' % (iy+1), value=0.4, min=-2.0,  max=2.0)
    fit_params.add( 'sig_%i' % (iy+1), value=0.3, min=0.01, max=3.0)

# but now constrain all values of sigma to have the same value
# by assigning sig_2, sig_3, .. sig_5 to be equal to sig_1
for iy in (2, 3, 4, 5):
    fit_params['sig_%i' % iy].expr='sig_1'

# run the global fit to all the data sets
result = minimize(objective, fit_params, args=(x, data))
report_fit(result)

# plot the data sets and fits
plt.figure()
for i in range(5):
    y_fit = gauss_dataset(fit_params, i, x)
    plt.plot(x, data[i, :], 'o', x, y_fit, '-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: There is no requirement that multiple datasets be the same length.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I edited the question to show the specific error I got when thing to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's and example of simultaneously fitting multiple (2) data sets of different sizes and forms:

Dataset 1:  Gaussian with amplitude, center, sigma
Dataset 2:  Decaying sine wave with amplitdue, frequency, decay, phase-shift

Let's assert that the Gaussian center is equal to the frequency and the Gaussian sigma squared is the decay parameter for the sine wave.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from lmfit import Parameters, minimize, report_fit
from lmfit.lineshapes import gaussian

# parameters for mock data
gaus_amp = 200
gaus_cen = 4.5
gaus_sig = 7.0

sine_amp = 17
sine_shift = -0.75
sine_freq = gaus_cen
sine_decay = gaus_sig**2

# dataset 1: gaussian
x1 = np.linspace(-30, 30, 121)
y1 = gaussian(x1, gaus_amp, gaus_cen, gaus_sig)
y1 += np.random.normal(scale=0.25, size=len(y1))

# dataset 2: decaying sine wave
x2 = np.linspace(0, 150, 601)
y2 = sine_amp * np.sin(sine_shift +x2/sine_freq) * np.exp(-x2**2/sine_decay**2)
y2 += np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=len(y2))

def objective(params, x1, x2, y1, y2):
    gamp = params['g_amp']
    gcen = params['g_cen']
    gsig = params['g_sig']
    gresid = y1 - gaussian(x1, gamp, gcen, gsig)

    samp = params['s_amp']
    sshift = params['s_shift']
    sfreq = gcen
    sdecay = gsig**2
    sresid = y2 - samp * np.sin(sshift +x2/sfreq) * np.exp(-x2**2/sdecay**2)

    # now concatenate the residuals of the data sets
    return np.concatenate((gresid, sresid))

params = Parameters()
params.add('g_amp', value=150, min=0)
params.add('g_cen', value=5, min=0)
params.add('g_sig', value=5, min=0)
params.add('s_amp', value=10, min=0)
params.add('s_shift', value=-0.5, min=-3, max=3)

# Run the fit and show the fitting result
out = minimize(objective, params, args=(x1, x2, y1, y2))
report_fit(out.params)
```

The key here is `np.concatenate()` to make a single 1-D residual array from the residuals of the individual datasets.

This example will run and print out the results of

```
[[Variables]]
    g_amp:    201.092389 +/- 1.74123974 (0.87%) (init = 150)
    g_cen:    4.50385672 +/- 0.00477268 (0.11%) (init = 5)
    g_sig:    7.00094469 +/- 0.01821519 (0.26%) (init = 5)
    s_amp:    16.8828293 +/- 0.08010449 (0.47%) (init = 10)
    s_shift: -0.74422074 +/- 0.00555315 (0.75%) (init = -0.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(g_cen, s_shift) = +0.7679
    C(g_sig, s_amp)   = -0.5904
    C(g_amp, g_sig)   = +0.1502
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to plot the fits to the two datasets and think about extending that to 30 datasets ;).